# Getting argument values of MethodCallExpression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

How can I get the arguments values of a MethodCallExpression?

Today I do this way, but isn´t fast enough:

```
private static object GetArgumentValue(Expression element)
{
    LambdaExpression l = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(element, element.Type));
    return l.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
}
```

This method get values from a Expression, but if I know that Expression always come from a MethodCallExpression.Arguments I can optimize it?

I think I can change first line to this, but I don't know if it works for all situations:

```
LambdaExpression l = Expression.Lambda(element);
```

Comment: You mean something like "object[] args = methodCallExpression.Arguments.Select(p => p.Value);"?

Comment: @Rodrigo That's what I'm looking for, but Value isn't a property of Expression.

Answer (score 4):

Cake

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Expression<Action<string>> action = a => Console.WriteLine("asdf");
            var mce = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;
            Console.WriteLine((mce.Arguments[0] as ConstantExpression).Value);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cake? (and then some filler text so the 5 letters comment can be posted)

Comment: Why are you assuming that arguments will always be constants?

Comment: because if it's not, you can't get anything out of it without .Compile()

Answer (score 3):

I would try this to return the object:

```
private static object _getValue(MethodCallExpression expression)
{
    var objectMember = Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(object));

    var getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(objectMember);

    var getter = getterLambda.Compile();

    return getter();
}
```

It is much faster then calling the following:

```
LambdaExpression l = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(element, element.Type));
return l.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

Comment: I am getting `System.InvalidOperationException: 'No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Void' and 'System.Object'.'`.  Running on .Net Core 2.

Comment: @ttugates, from the error it looks like the lambda method you are calling returns a void, but this line `Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(objectMember)` expects the function to return an object

Comment: because its a Func and not an Action.  Cool.  Don't recall what I was testing against at the time.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
private static object GetArgumentValue(Expression element)
{
    if (element is ConstantExpression)
    {
        return (element as ConstantExpression).Value;
    }

    var l = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(element, element.Type));
    return l.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
}
```

It is combining the [OP's original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432865/getting-argument-values-of-methodcallexpression) with [Sleeper Smith's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432865/getting-argument-values-of-methodcallexpression#answer-6067576).